# How to create an interactive nav bar in HTML?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

to learn HTML more in depth I'm building the website of a famous fashion brand, trying to emulate and build all the functions that I see with the HTML knowledge that I have. I still haven't learned CSS, but I would like to know how to lay the html basics for a nav bar that, when hovered, drops down a menu with anchors to other sites and forms.

This is what I've tried so far.
The HTML:

```
    <header>
        <nav>

            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Brand Name" title="Brand Name" width="250" loading="lazy">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="navElement-nuoviArrivi">
                        <div class="nuoviArrivi">NUOVI ARRIVI</div>
                        <div class="dropdown-nuoviArrivi">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="https://link.com"></a>Coats</li>
                                <li><a href="https://link.com"></a>Shoes</li>
                                <li><a href="https://link.com"></a>Belts</li>
                                <li><a href="https://link.com"></a>Sweaters</li>
                                <li><a href="https://link.com"></a>Jewelry</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li><!--Other Nav Element with the same code structure--></li>
                <li><!--Other Nav Element with the same code structure--></li>
                <li><!--Other Nav Element with the same code structure--></li>
                <li><!--Other Nav Element with the same code structure--></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

The CSS I found on W3:

```
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.navElement-nuoviArrivi {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

  .dropdown-nuoviArrivi {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-nuoviArrivi a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .navElement-nuoviArrivi:hover .dropdown-nuoviArrivi {display: block;}
```

Comment: read into flexbox. And dont mistake w3school with W3C. They are not even related. w3school isn general is a poor website to learn HTML, CSS and JS in a modern standard.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're on the right track to create a dropdown menu in your navigation bar using HTML and CSS. However, there are a few adjustments needed to make it functional.

```css
/* The container <li> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.navElement {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the dropdown links */
.dropdown ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.navElement:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Brand Name" title="Brand Name" width="250" loading="lazy">
            <ul>
                <li class="navElement">
                    <a href="#">NUOVI ARRIVI</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://link.com">Coats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://link.com">Shoes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://link.com">Belts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://link.com">Sweaters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://link.com">Jewelry</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Add more navigation items here -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code I provided

I've enhanced the navigation menu by making "NUOVI ARRIVI" clickable with an `<a>` element, wrapping each menu item in `<li>`
elements with the class navElement, and amended the CSS selectors and
rules to style the dropdown links.

But obviously this is very basic it's up to you to customise it the way you want.